# Do the Biddies need to stay by Alder all the time?

Tags: motherland-fort-salem

We see in *Motherland: Fort Salem* that the head of the U.S. witch army, General Sarah Alder, is always surrounded by 5-6 Biddies, witches who take on her age and allow her to be several centuries old while still in a young body.

One of them dying causes Alder to age quickly, as seen in the season 1 and 2 finales. Why then don't they stay at Fort Salem (or at least the chopper, in the Tarim situation in season 1) or some other place when General Alder is on the field?

Is this a "benefits over risks" (risk getting them to die, by bringing them into battle, but be able to protect them if something happens) situation, or do they *have* to be close to Alder for the spell to work?

(I'm thinking there's no real "don't lock them up, it will deprive them of their individual liberties" argument, since the Biddies don't seem to have any individuality or former sense of self.)